# How to pass Image and Some data as a parameter to web API Controller through Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to pass topicmedia and image file to web api post controller through jquery ajax. but not accomplish this task i am trying this from last 2 days. please any one tell this.

[Ajax Code Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Lxk.jpg)

[Web API Controller Action Here i want to get data and image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTicV.jpg)

```
$('#add').click(function () {
var topicmedia = {"topicid":"","createon":""};
            topicmedia.topicid = 1;
            topicmedia.createon = $('#txtCreateOn').val();
            var data = new FormData();
            var file = $("#img").get(0).files;
            data.append("file", file);
            debugger;
            $.ajax({     
                url: 'http://localhost:4728/api/TopicMedias',
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
               // processData: false,
                data: JSON.stringify(topicmedia, file),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function () {
                    $('#successfullModel').modal('show');
                }
      });
  });
```

that is the code of web api where i want to get 2 parameters topicmedia which contain topicid and createon data and file parameter recive image

```
  public IHttpActionResult PostTopicMedia(TopicMedia topicMedia, HttpPostedFile files)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

}

After geting the image and data in web api action i want to save image in folder and other data and image path want to save in database table topicmedia which have datapath, topicid and createOn field.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, It is much more helpful if you post the text of your code rather than images. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: added code please check this

Comment: What is `HttpPostedFile`? Is it [HttpPostedFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfile?view=netframework-4.7.2)? `HttpPostedFile` is in `System.Web.dll`, do you develop with `asp.net web api` or `asp.net core web api`?

Answer (score 1):

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostImage()
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
        if (postedFile != null && postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            IList<string> AllowedFileExtensions = new List<string>{".jpg", ".png"};
            var ext = postedFile.FileName.Substring(postedFile.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
            var extension = ext.ToLower();
            if (!AllowedFileExtensions.Contains(extension))
            {
                var message = string.Format("Please Upload image of type .jpg, .png.");
                dict.Add("error", message);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, dict);
            }
            else
            {
                var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/yourDirectory/" + postedFile.FileName + extension);
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
        }

        var successMsg = string.Format("Image Updated Successfully.");
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, successMsg);
    }

    var res = string.Format("Please Upload a image.");
    dict.Add("error", res);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, dict);
}
```